Lite-Server running script twice, interjecting wrong HTML tag
I have a simple website built using Node.js and TypeScript, which is prepared for distribution through webpack. When I open the output in browser, it works just fine. However, if I open the page using lite-server and browser-sync, I get an odd error - the script is run twice and odd HTML is interjected. How do I fix this? I am out of ideas (I am also a beginner with Node.js and related).
Relevant part of index.html; JS console gives back error "404 file not found".
<head>
    <script type = "module" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo-container">
        /*The upper <img>-tag is the wrong one, the lower one loads just fine.
        <img src="http://localhost:3000/browser-sync/images/287cb8e0d137623f010f.png">
        <img src="http://localhost:3000/images/287cb8e0d137623f010f.png">
    </div>
</body>
...

In addition console shows that the script is ran twice, first with the prefix VM11.
Relevant part of scripts.ts
import $ from 'jquery';
import logoImage from './img/logo.png';
import logoMedicine from './img/medicine.png';

$(function(){

    
    document.getElementsByClassName('logo-container')[0]?.appendChild(imgElement);
    document.getElementById('rx_img')?.appendChild(medicineImage);
});

webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/scripts.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'},
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'scripts.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};

tsconfig.js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "src",
        "index.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
  }

package.json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "lite-server --baseDir=\"./dist\"",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.14.11",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.*",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.30",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}


After taking a long walk through the woods, I figured it out.
My HTML template included the .js file via a script tag. Webpack duplicated this tag, i.e., my script was included twice. This created the odd behavior by lite-server.
Lesson learned: don't include the .js file in your HTML template if you're running the setup above.
